# UNREAL ENGINE - How do I set the gamemode variables on level open?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I have this widget that a player can use to create a game, choose a map, and choose a gamemode.

[Session Creation Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IovrR.png)

And I've been able to open the map AND set the gamemode that the player chose by putting a reference of it in the options.

[Setting Gamemode in Options on Level Open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SUS3.png)

Now I have some settings that the player can also edit that needs to be set in the chosen gamemode.

[Gamemode Variables that Need to Be Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ6Es.png)

So is there a way of passing something in the options to set specific variables?

PS: Stack Overflow isn't allowing me to post images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them in the options string as well.

`AGameModeBase` has a string member called `OptionsString`, which you can read during your game mode initialization.

You can use the `UGameplayStatics` helper functions `HasOption`, `ParseOption`, `GetIntOption` to check for the option values you passed in.